# Codeigniter Pagination button style

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

```
$config['next_link'] = 'Continue';
$config['next_tag_open'] = '<button type="button" name="next" id="next" class="btn btn-primary">';
$config['next_tag_close'] = '</button>';
```

Above are my Next button, it works actually, just because the next_link is a  hyperlink, that means I must only click on the Continue word instead of the button. Any way can improve this?

Comment: what is your exact need?

Comment: My button is a rectangle box style, when I click Continue button I must click exactly the word instead of the surrounded area. <button type="button" name="next" id="next" class="btn btn-primary"><a href="http://localhost/data/1">Continue</a></button>

Comment: Instead of button, you can do with css.

Comment: You mean change the a css?

Comment: yes. You want l=button like style but text only clickable. right?

Comment: I want the whole button clickable not necessary must click on the word to trigger next page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change button to span / div.

```
$config['next_link'] = 'Continue';
$config['next_tag_open'] = '<span class="btn btn-primary">';
$config['next_tag_close'] = '</span>';
```

Then change css to make `a` link look like button.

For ex:

```
.btn a
{
   background-color:#CCC;
   padding:10px;
}
```

While using padding, those 10px also clickable.